# Finite corrections to the Higgs mass in SUSY

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, renormalization, higgs, fine-tuning

I am worried here about specific supersymmetric scenarios in which an energy scale above the TeV is introduces. An example would be the Seesaw extension of the Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model. My questions is:

In such a scenario, and even though SUSY guarantees a cancellation of the quadratic divergences afflicting the Higgs mass, isn't it true that large *finite* corrections to the Higgs mass appear nonetheless - for instance proportional to the Majorana mass in the Seesaw example? Can SUSY cancel those as well?